# critical point of $f(x,y) = -(y-2x^{2})(y-3x^{2})$ is only (0,0)

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

i have to prove that the only critical point of the function
$$ f(x,y) = -(y-2x^{2})(y-3x^{2}) $$
is $(0,0)$

For that i calculated the partial derivatives of f:

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 10xy-24x^{3} $

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 5x^{2}-2y $

Now i set $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 $ and $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $.

I calculated this:

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 \Leftrightarrow 10xy-24x^{3}=0$

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0 \Leftrightarrow 5x^{2}-2y=0 \Leftrightarrow y= \frac{5}{2}x^{2}$

Now i did put $y$ from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in $y$ in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ :

$10x(\frac{5}{2}x^{2})-24x^{3}=0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{50}{2}x^{3}-24x^{3}=0 \Leftrightarrow 25x^{3}-24x^{3}=0 \Leftrightarrow x^{3}=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$

When i put now x again back in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ i get:

$y= \frac{5}{2}0^{2} \Leftrightarrow y=0$

Is this enough and does this makes even sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything looks correct. In order for $(x,y)$ to be a critical point, both partial derivatives  must vanish, and you showed that in order for this to happen, both must be simultaneously zero.

Comment: tanks you very much. now i am relieved :-)

Comment: @hukachaka no problem, good work :).